# Unity - GetComponent on Instantiated Object returning Null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to access a script on another gameobject that is instantiated in my script, and no matter what I do the script always returns null.

I instantiate the gameobject first by doing this.

```
asteroid = (GameObject)Instantiate(asteroidPrefab);
```

after that I try acessing its script by doing this:

```
AsteroidHandler handler = (AsteroidHandler)asteroid.GetComponent(typeof(AsteroidHandler));
```

To check whether or not the handler was set properly I did this:

```
if(handler == null){
    Debug.Log("Asteroid Handler is Null");
}else{
    Debug.Log("Asteroid Handler was setup properly");
}
```

The problem is this always does the null option. I have the AsteroidHandler script attached to the asteroidPrefab prefab, and when I Instantiate it, it Instantiates properly, as I see the asteroid on the screen. Still when I try accessing the AsteroidHandler script that is attatched to it, it seems to act like it isn't there;

I have tried a couple other methods to access AsteroidHandler but they all say its null:

```
AsteroidHandler handler = (AsteroidHandler)asteroid.GetComponent<AsteroidHandler>();
```

.

```
AsteroidHandler handler = (AsteroidHandler)asteroid.GetComponent(typeof(AsteroidHandler)) as Asteroid Handler;
```

I have looked at a couple other questions similar to mine, but none of the answers seem to help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have the script on the prefab

Comment: check if everything is attached to the prefab and it is saved within the project (not just in hierarchy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't be easier,

add this code

```
asteroid = (GameObject)Instantiate(asteroidPrefab);
// add this...
asteroid.name = "Added test item";
```

run the program and wait until you see the *"Added test item"*

Check, do you ALSO see the *"Asteroid Handler is Null"*

Now, literally look in your Heirarchy for the scene, and find the object named **Added test item**

Look carefully at the Inspector, see what you see.

Comment: ugh I am so stupid. When I did this, the object that was changed to "Added test item" was another object. Basically the prefab I put in for the asteroidPrefab in the unity editor wasn't the right prefab so it didn't have the script in it. This definitely seems like a good way to test if your instantiated object has instantiated properly and that it is the right object XD. Thank you, and I'm sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid problem.

Comment: You're hardly stupid, you're clearly a naturally talented developer, **since the first thing you did was add a Debug.Log line** as you mention. Outstanding! That's the mark of excellence.  Cheers!

Comment: If you are new to Unity, here's an incredibly useful post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890932/unity-game-manager-script-works-only-one-time/35891919#35891919