# How can I fix MissingReferenceException that is telling me game object is destroyed when I didn't destroy it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code that looks like this.

```
public static Dictionary<int, Action> functionsMap;
void Function()
{
    if (!isDictionaryInitialized)
    {
        functionsMap = new Dictionary<int, Action>();

        functionsMap.Add(1, () => StartCoroutine(Function1()));
        functionsMap.Add(1, () => StartCoroutine(Function2()));
    }
 }

void CheckForFunction()
{
    var r = currentFunctionNumber;

    if (functionsMap.TryGetValue(r, out currentAction)) { currentAction(); }
}
```

The code works fine when I start my program. However if I go to another scene and then return to it, I get this error.

> "MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'ScriptName' has been
>   destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should
>   either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object."

The problem is I have never destroyed the object. Initially I didn't have bool `isDictionaryInitialized` and I defined the new `Dictionary` outside of the Function because I thought the error was related to my program trying to access a `Dictionary` that was deleted after the scene was closed. I get the same problem with or without the bool, and regardless of where I define the `Dictionary.`

What is causing this, and what is the reason so I can avoid making the same mistake?

Edit: This question was marked as duplicate, but the link I don't believe applies to my situation, or if it does I don't understand how. It says static objects are not reloaded on a scene change, and the Dictionary is defined as a static object. I also tried changing it to non-static and the result is the same.

I have dozens of gameobjects in my code and don't have this issue with any other object, so I assume the problem is related to how the dictionary object is defined. Is there a way to keep the Dictionary object from being destroyed on scene change? I don't have it as a game object in the scene, it's just defined in the code itself as a public static Dictionary. Could someone tell me what I need to do differently please and thank you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading scene causes scripts to stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191957/reloading-scene-causes-scripts-to-stop-working)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be caused by changing scenes because simply loading another scene would destroy all gameobject in the current scene.

According to [Object.DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

> The load of a new Scene destroys all current Scene objects.

To solve this, you can either use `DontDestroyOnLoad` function to mark the object you want to be kept before loading another scene, or using different way to load like [LoadSceneMode.Additive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html) without destroying the current scene.

Comment: Thank you, I'm familiar with DontDestroyOnLoad but doesn't that have to be applied to a gameobject? How can I apply DontDestroyOnLoad to a public static Dictionary? Using DontDestroyOnLoad(functionsMap) doesn't work. Or do I need to declare it as a gameobject within the script with public gameobject = functionsMap, or something like that?

Comment: After your Edit, I found that the dictionary is not a gameobject. And my solution won't be applied. I'm guessing that you are using a static variable to keep the reference of the dictionary. And you must initialize the dictionary in a script that attached to a gameobject and assign it to the static variable. Can you post how you do it . It would be helpful.

Comment: I edited my original question, but i have it declared as public static Dictionary<int, Action> functionsMap; at the beginning of the class. Then I call the function in the original post periodically when the scene is open. I was going to just define all of the keys when declaring the function, but that causes errors with other parts of my code because I use IEnumerators and apparently I can't reference IEnumerators in a Monobehavior class from the error I received. I'm open to other ways to solve the problem, it's not necessary for the dictionary to be defined after the scene starts

Comment: Since the variables are constant, I'm just new to using Dictionary objects in C# so I'm unsure the proper way to do it. I know it's a lot easier than I'm making it, I just don't know the proper syntax.

Comment: Can you explain more on how you call the Function() and how it gets executed? Does the class you define attached to any gameobjects in the scene?

Comment: Sorry, you must not attach the class to a gameobject because it's not a gameobject. I want to know more about how you initialize the dictionary.

Comment: I declare the dictionary before run-time, then when I start the scene I run the function in the original post which initializes the dictionary and sets a bool isDictionaryInitialized, so that if the function is called again it doesn't try to initialize the dictionary a second time (Otherwise I get an error that the key already exists). I then have another function CheckForFunction that is called periodically every few seconds, and it uses a randomly generated number to determine which action is used from the Dictionary.

Comment: Do you call the Function from another script which is attached to a gameobject ?

Comment: I use the Update function in the script to listen for a bool that's toggled by another script. When that happens, the script runs CheckForFunction and references the dictionary keys. So the function isn't directly called from another script, no.

Comment: Is it possible the error is caused by executing null reference of currentAction? I'm guessing the dictionary object still exists but the currentAction does not since the gameobject has the function already been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

First you are adding two `Action`s to your Dictionary but both with the same `key`.

```
functionsMap.Add(1, () => StartCoroutine(Function1()));
functionsMap.Add(1, () => StartCoroutine(Function2()));
```

wouldn't this overwrite the first entry?

---

Than your general problem is:

While `functionsMap` is `static` the two actions / one action you added are non-static (`StartCoroutine` always requires an instance of `MonoBehaviour` to run on) and therefore only available for the according component! (You talked about an Update method so this has to be a `MonoBehaviour` attached to a GameObject in your first scene.)

Now if you change the Scene, the GameObject holding that component is probably destroyed if you are not using [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

The result is that your `static` Dictionary stays intact and filled meaning the entry with `key = 1` still exists **but** the `Value` namely the added non-static `Action` is no longer available.

To avoid that you should add

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
```

either in `Awake` or `Start` to prevent the `GameObject` holding the component and thereby holding the `Action` that belongs to the reference(s) in the entry in your Dictionary.

Comment: How did you fix this issue?