# "NullReference" when I tried to respawn the Player when enter collision or fall in to the void

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got an error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
`PlayerCollision.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision collisionInfo)`

(at Assets/Scripts/PlayerCollision.cs:15)
"
[image]

I tried to make a script when I enter collision ill respawn but it works only on the first try but it don't work on the second try.

Comment: As is seems, the problem is on line 15, that is probably because the is couldn't find "GameManager"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

oh for some reason in the build settings i got checked level1 then i unchecked it and it does not have any error now but thanks

Comment: Your GameManager seems to be only initialized in one scene (presumably level0). You could introduce an Prefab of the GameManager and make it an [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890932/unity-game-manager-script-works-only-one-time/35891919#35891919)